# How to get Attachment Id of a file uploaded in Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have posts and I upload a file like PDF or MS Word file(Not feature Images) in every post. I want to make downloadable link of that uploaded file. But I can't get attachment ID. Here is my code

```
<?php 
$reports = array(   
 'post_type' => 'post' , 
 'posts_per_page' => 3,
 'category_name' => 'reports'); 
    
 $q_reports = new WP_Query($reports);   
                
 if($q_reports->have_posts()){
 while($q_reports->have_posts()){ 
 $q_reports->the_post();?> 

<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id); ?>" ><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
```

I don't know how can I get `$attach_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_attached_media` to get all attachments for a particular post. It takes the attachment type as the first parameter, note that you simply can use `"images"` for all images of any type, `"video"` for any videos and `"audio"` for any audio files. However to get documents, you need to specify the **mime type**. FYI You can see all allowed mime types using `print_r(get_post_mime_type());`

so you can use it to get all attachments of a specific type like this:

- **Images** (any type): `$attachments = get_attached_media("images", $post->ID );`
- **PDFs**: `$attachments = get_attached_media("", $post->ID );`
- **Word DOCX files**: `$attachments = get_attached_media("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", $post->ID );`

If you need to check for **multiple mime types** (e.g. PDF and DOCX), you will need to call the function for each type. Alternatively if you know you that all the attachments will be the file types you want, you can get *all* attached files like this:

```
$attachments = get_attached_media("images", $post->ID );
```

Example for your code:

```
<?php 
$reports = array(   
   'post_type' => 'post' , 
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'category_name' => 'reports'); 
    
$q_reports = new WP_Query($reports);   
                
if($q_reports->have_posts()){
    while($q_reports->have_posts()){ 
        $q_reports->the_post();

        /* Get all attachments and loop through them to display the link & post title */
        $attachments = get_attached_media("");
        foreach ($attachments as $file){ ?>
            <a href='<?php echo $file["guid"]; ?>' ><?php echo $file["post_title"]; ?></a>
        <?php }

    endwhile; 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: It almost solve my problem except that if I remove attachment from post, removed attachment are also displayed.

Comment: @NirdoshShrestha When you say "remove attachment from post", but you mean you delete it from the post editor? WP_Query works on files that are attached to the post rather than just included in the content, so you also need to "unattach" the attachment in the Media Library - its simply just clicking the "Detach" link in Media Library, you can [see instructions how to detach a file here](https://silicondales.com/tutorials/wordpress/unattach-images-media-wordpress/#How_to_Unattach_Images_(and_other_media)_in_WordPress)

Comment: It works partially. WP user will remove file from post only. User will not detach file from media library.

Comment: @NirdoshShrestha That is a different question - each question on Stack Overflow should be about one single problem/task. This was about how to get the attachment id, so you can ask a new question here about how to detach an attachment in PHP and we will be able to answer! Just make sure to explain what you want to do (and clarify whether you want to detach or delete the attachment). You can reference this question in your new question for context.